# Micronaut view rendering without template engine

Tags: micronaut, viewrendering

Can micronaut render static files?

I added `compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-views'` into `build.gradle`

The Controller:

```
@Controller("/main")
public class MainController {

    @View("index.html")
    @Get("/")
    public HttpResponse index() {
        return HttpResponse.ok();
    }
}
```

The `index.html` file is under `/src/main/resources/views/index.html`

A requesting `localhost:8080/main` does not render the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is behaving as designed. There is no point in applying view model logic when there is no way to apply the model to the view.

You can achieve the desired effect by simply configuring [static resources](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#staticResources). For example:

```
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      main:
        paths: classpath:views
        mapping: /main/**
```

With the above configuration an `index.html` file in `src/main/resources/views` will be served when the `/main` URL is accessed.

Comment: Great, that will definitely do. Thanks!