# How to serve html using micronaut framework?

Tags: micronaut

I understand that micronaut is a framework for microservices. How to serve HTML pages & javascript using micronaut? I have a REST api built using micronaut. As of now, the application is too simple that having another client application to consume the REST API and then another runtime to run the client application is not required.

So I am looking for options to build web app using micronaut framework.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972051/micronaut-view-rendering-without-template-engine/55975629. See my answer there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Micronaut view rendering without template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972051/micronaut-view-rendering-without-template-engine)